# How to host two web sites on one IP? IIS

Tags: hosting, iis-6

I'm a developer, and since I'm not that skilled with server stuff, I wanted to ask, is it possible to have multiple web sites on one IP?

Say:

```
foo.com -> 111.222.333.444
bar.com -> 111.222.333.444
```

The sites are different `foo.com != bar.com`

Platform is Windows server/IIS6

Comment: Duplicate of about a hundred questions on here and a couple thousand google results. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. You need to configure host header names for each web site.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287

Comment: Unless you're using SSL, in which case you need an IP address (and certificate) for each site.

Comment: It is possible to use SSL in IIS 6 web sites that use host headers. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Glad to help...